# How I can "catch" gerrit event on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am using Gerrit plug in with jenkinsfile.
After setting trigger for gerrit rebase via excludeTrivialRebase: false I still want to implement some logic on that event.

GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE after rebase set to "patchset-created" so it is not a good indication for rebase event.

Is there any other parameter that can be indicating the rebase event or any other solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but you have the following options:

```
excludeDrafts       : true|false
excludeTrivialRebase: true|false
excludeNoCodeChange : true|false
```

Comment: Assuming I enabled excludeTrivialRebase and excludeDrafts.  After the job was triggered, how can I know the reason why it triggered ? Because of Drafts or Rebase ?

Comment: If I understand correctly now, you're trying to know if the change was a rebase or not? There's no way to accomplish with gerrit-trigger options or parameters.